# Different between regex in "find" box and "replace" box, Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I'm trying to do a find/replace in Eclipse using the following pattern: `\$.*}`.
If I put this into the "find" search box in Eclipse I can find all the matches in a file (e.g. `${MASTER_KEY}`). However, I'm not sure what to put in the "replace" box. My goal is to replace `${MASTER_KEY}` with `$'{MASTER_KEY}'`. I tried `'\$.*}'`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search By this:

```
\$\{(.*?)\}
```

and replace by this:

```
\$'\{\1\}'
```

Explanation:

`{.*}` will match "**${abc}pqr${def}**" as a single match which will be wrong in your case. Whereas  `.*?` makes it lazy thus it will match **${abc}**  and **${def}** separately which you need.

Comment: What's the difference between `\$\{(.*?)\}` and `\$\{(.*)\}`?

Comment: @Adam I have included the explanation for you query